# Search ,identify duplicate data in an excel file and reformat it using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have to process an excel file using pandas. The excel file has three columns as shown here(sample)
[excelfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XVzI.png). The 'LicNo' column is not unique.

- My Task-1:

I have to group it by 'LicNo' to bring all 'Licensees' in the same row. In the grouped table there will be 'LicNo' and a bunch of 'Licensee' columns only(all in a row) ignoring the middle column in the original excel file.

- My Task-2:

Now to identify the duplicates, I have to search if the 'Licensee' in the first column is repeated in the subsequent columns (i.e.axis-1). The search will be based on the first word in the text in the first column; if this is repeated in the next columns to declare it as 'Possible duplicates'
Here is the code that I wrote:

```
enter code here
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain
df=pd.read_excel("compare_usr.xlsx",dtype={'LicNo': int,'ScheduleNo':str, 'Licensee': str})
#df.isna().any()
df=df.dropna(axis='index')
df['Licensee'] = df.Licensee.str.replace(r'\n', '')
#to make the strings uniform as in certain  fields the M/s is present.
df["Licensee"]=df.Licensee.str.replace("M/s ","") 
# the character ';' is inserted to segregate the duplicate LicNo while transposing into rows
df.loc[:,"Licensee"]=df["Licensee"].astype(str)+";"
def func(x):
    ch = chain.from_iterable(y.split(';') for y in x.tolist())
    return '\n'.join(((ch)))      
dfNew=df.groupby('LicNo') ['Licensee'].apply(func).str.split("\n+",expand=True)#.to_excel("test2.xls")
```

## the following two lines marked as (1) and (2) does not produce the desired output and not in the code. The below function code (fun(row)) however produce the intended result.

```
 #dfNew['Status']=np.where((dfNew[x+1].str.contains(dfNew[0].str,na=False) for x in col),"match","unmatch") # (1)
#dfNew['Status']=np.where((dfNew[x+1].str.apply(lambda y: dfNew[0].str in y) for x in range(6)),"match","unmatch") #(2)

# in the original Excel file there are about 4000 rows and it   produced 18 columns of duplicates.   
enter code here


def fun(row):
    col=[i+1 for i in range(17)] 
    for i in col:
       if row[i] is None:
          continue
    #to extract the first word from row[0]

    if (row[0].split()[0].lower() in row[i].lower()):
        return True
return False
dfNew['Status']=np.where(dfNew.apply(fun,axis=1)==True,dfNew.index,"May be duplicate or only in   one file")
```

Now my question is I would like to replace the function 'fun(row)' (this is working and producing the desired result) with either of the two lines marked as (1) and (2) in the code to produce the dfNew['Status'] . I am not able to appreciate what is going wrong in either of these two line as both produces wrong result.
I am a beginner code writer in Python and owe to stackflow.com for copying the codes from some of the answers in some other topic. Would you be able to help me?
Thanks.
Edit:
Desired outcome:-
[The result file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yclwh.jpg)

Comment: you don't need looping here, can you show us your sample data and expected output?

Comment: You have given your code, and it is a nice thing. But you only gave the input sample data as an image, so we would have to type it by hand do reproduce (and I am much too lazy for it...). You should put the data as copyable text in the question itself if you want to get answers here.

Comment: Thanks. How to do that ? I tried to copy as a CSV file ,but it looks like garbled.